# TFS2013 web access syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting

The Team Foundation Server 2013 Team Web Access site performs syntax highlighting for C# and Javascript, but not for Python or C++. Is there any extension which adds syntax highlighting for those and other languages?

Comment: No(t yet). Web Access is not officially extensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python [is already supported](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/news/2013-sep-30-vso) in Visual Studio Team Services and will be on-premise in a "[Future Update](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/news/release-archive-vso)" - which *was* the Name for Update 1, however, it looks like the "Update 1" moniker will be used for [Visual Studio only](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/12/09/visual-studio-2013-1-rc-is-available.aspx), but I'm confident MS will include it with the next update to TFS 2013 on-premise.